# Windows>XAMPP>Magento 2>Chrome.... Broken out of Box

Tags: php, magento, xampp, magento2, magento2.2

This is the admin panel of my newly installed, unaltered install of Magento 2.2.5 in XAMPP 7.0.30 / PHP 7.0.30:

[image: Console log from chrome.]
I am brand new to this, but I have done my best to find an answer or even just a solution on my own. I need help.

I do not see any folder with the path localhost/pub/static/**version1532138534**/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/

I've been struggling with this all week. I've fresh installed both XAMPP and Magento, trying multiple versions.

I've tried different browsers, and changing my browsers settings, and clearing my browsers.

I've tried installing XAMPP and Magento on MacOS instead, and found a new issue, that prevented me from even getting to this step, which I then banged my head against for 6 hours or so before giving up and going back to Windows.

I've pored over the web trying to find a solutions, but I can't even find anyone with the same issue.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong... and I want to know what, but I just can't seem to find any answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution:
If anyone is having the same issue, here is what worked for me.

I added "C:\xampp\php" to my system variables/path.

1. Search "System Properties" from the start menu and open it.(New Window)
2. Select the "Advanced" tab.
3. Click "Environment Variables". (New Window)
4. From "System Variables", select "Path".
5. Click "Edit"
6. Click "New"
7. Type "C:\xampp\php"
8. Hit "OK" x3.

This appears to have allowed me to use php commands in my command prompt.

Then, I ran the setup for the Magento file in "C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\bin". (This may be redundant.)
[You can see a full list of available commands with "C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\bin php Magento"]

1. Open a command prompt. (win+r, cmd, enter).
2. Navigate to the bin folder. (cd c:\xampp\htdocs\Magento{*this may be unique to your setup}\bin, enter)
3. Run the setup. (php Magento setup:install)

Finally, I deployed all static view files.

1. In the same directory as before deploy static files. (php Magento setup:static-content:deploy, enter)

After this, in a browser, I navigated to localhost/Magento, and ran through the Magento setup again, and the issue is resolved.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAEIQ.png

Answer (score 0):

do the static content deployment.

take backup of core_config_data table

go to phpmyadmin and run `insert core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);`

go to your magento root folder using command line.

run `php bin\magento cache:flush`

run `php bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

your problem will be resolved.